# The map $B(X,Y) \to B(Y^*, X^*), T \mapsto T^*$ is not necessarily onto.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

There is the following result:

> Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces. Then the map $T \mapsto T^*$ is an isometric isomorphism from $B(X,Y)$ into $B(Y^*, X^*)$.

I want to show the map $T \mapsto T^*$ is not necessarily onto. In order to do so, I consider the Banach spaces $B(\mathbb{F}, c_0)$ and $B(c_0^*, \mathbb{F}^*)$ and want to show that there is no continuous map $T \mapsto T^*$ from $B(\mathbb{F}, c_0)$ onto $B(c_0^*, \mathbb{F}^*)$. That is, there is an operator in $B(c_0^*, \mathbb{F}^*)$ that is not the adjoint of an operator in $B(\mathbb{F}, c_0)$.

Comment: Here's a related question.  It is clear that the map $T\mapsto T^*$ is onto whenever $Y$ is reflexive. Does the converse hold too? Suppose $Y$ is a nonreflexive normed space and $X$ is an arbitrary normed space. Can we always find an operator $A\in B(Y^*,X^*)$ which is not weak*-to-weak* continuous? Note that the method in the answer below will not work for this more general question, as, for instance, the James space is nonreflexive and yet is isomorphic to its second dual.

Comment: @BenWallis. Why is the map $T \mapsto T^*$ onto whenever $Y$ is reflexive? It is not clear to me.

Comment: See Proposition 3.7 here:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03241

Comment: Thanks. I had the same line of reasoning when $X,Y$ are supposed to be reflexive. I did not think of the weak-to-weak$^*$ continuity of your operator $T$. Something else: the point is that $Y$ should be reflexive, isn't it? In your paper you assume that $Y^*$ is reflexive, which is equivalent for Banach spaces, but not for normed spaces.

Comment: Good observation. Proposition 3.7 is valid even for normed spaces instead of Banach spaces. However, at a minimum, $Y^*$ being reflexive needs to be substituted in the other question. Otherwise if we take, for instance, $Y=$ the (nonclosed) linear span of a Hilbert space basis, that will violate the conjecture since it is not reflexive but satisfies $T\mapsto T^*$ being surjective for any choice of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint/check:

- $B(\mathbb F, c_0)$ is isometric to $c_0$,
- $B(c_0^* ,\mathbb F^*)$ is isometric to $c_0^{**}$,
- Under this identification, the mapping $T\mapsto T^*$ can be treated as the canonical embedding $c_0 \to c_0^{**}$.

Key word: [Reflexive Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space)

Comment: Thanks. I see $B(c_0^*, \mathbb{F}) \cong c_0^{**} \cong \ell^{\infty}$, and I believe your first point is correct, but could you expand a bit on this one? Is it because the space is closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: (And $c_0^{\ast\ast}=\ell_\infty$, canonically.)

Comment: Consider the mapping $B(\mathbb F, c_0) \to c_0$, $f \mapsto f(1)$. @jvnv

Comment: @ArcticChar Great. So, in general: $B(\mathbb{F}, X) \cong X$. I did not think of it.